# What does it mean by the use of brackets in this code

Tags: f#

I have a code snippet here but i don't understand the use of "new (code)" in it.

```
type Product (code:string, price:float) = 
   let isFree = price=0.0 
   new (code) = Product(code,0.0)
   member this.Code = code 
   member this.IsFree = isFree
```

Specifically why the need to enclose the "code" variable inside brackets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a constructor. From [MSDN: Classes (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233205.aspx) (see section 'Constructors'):

> You can add additional constructors by using the new keyword to add a member, as follows:
>
> `new (argument-list) = constructor-body`

In your example, the `Product` type has one default constructor which accepts `code` and `price`, and one additional constructor that takes only `code` and applies the default constructor with `0.0` for `price`. In this case, the parentheses around `code` are not strictly required, and the code would compile just the same without it, although it would be required if you want constructor that takes zero parameters or more than one parameter.

The equivalent C# would be something like this:

```cs
public class Product
{
    private string code;
    private bool isFree;

    public Product(string code, double price) {
        this.code = code;
        this.isFree = price == 0.0;
    }
    
    public Product(string code) : this(code, 0.0) { }
    
    public string Code { get { return this.code; } }
    public float IsFree { get { return this.isFree; } }
}
```